# How to add Bootstrap Accordion to Angular app

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to add an Bootstrap Accordion to my Angular app below:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
            Anim
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Collapsible Group Item #
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I ran the following NPM installations before building:

> npm i bootstrap
>
> npm i ngx-bootstrap

But when I click on one of the Accordion Titles, nothing is happening.
Can someone please tell me what piece of the set up I'm missing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

You are using the "plain" version of bootstrap.

1. Assure that you have added the bootstrap styling to your application in your global `styles.css` or `style.scss` file:

   **CSS Version**

   `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

   **SCSS Version**

   `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`
2. Import the `AccordionModule` from `ngx-bootstrap` to your `AppModule`.

   ```
   import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';

   @NgModule({
     imports: [AccordionModule.forRoot(),...]
   })
   export class AppModule{}
   ```
3. Use the component available in `ngx-bootstrap` not the "plain" html version:

   ```
   <accordion>
     <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
       This content is straight in the template.
     </accordion-group>
     <accordion-group heading="Another group">
       <p>Some content</p>
     </accordion-group>
     <accordion-group heading="Another group">
       <p>Some content</p>
     </accordion-group>
     <accordion-group heading="Another group">
       <p>Some content</p>
     </accordion-group>
   </accordion>
   ```

[Install instructions for ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#installation-instructions)

[Accordion Component of ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion)

**Add animation**

To add an animation you need to add the property `isAnimated` to the parent component `accordion`:

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true">
<!-- ... -->
</accordion>
```

**Open only one accordion**

To open only one accordion you need to add the property `closeOthers` to the parent component `accordion`:

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true" [closeOthers]="true">
<!-- ... -->
</accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my code with your suggestions & the accordion opens & closes now. But the transition isn't as smooth as the accordion shown [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/)

Comment: Also, the accordion in the above link - if you open 1 accordion, all the others close. Whereas with your code, if you open 1 accordion, any ones that were open at that time remain open

Comment: See my updated answer. I would suggest that you look into the documentation of the accordion of ngx-bootstrap to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command,

```
npm install bootstrap@4 jquery --save
```

After edit the **Angular.json** file modify `"style":["put here your bootstrap.css file "]` & `"script":["put here 1st jquery path and then bootstrap.js path"]`