# Bootstrap accordion not working in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working with Angular 9
Installed bootstrap and jquery following is entry in my package.json

    `"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",`
 
imported css and js files in angular.json like below

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
 "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

And added following code in my html body

```html
<body>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          Body1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          Body2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          Body 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But when i click Accordion i am getting following error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:1509)
at Function.each (jquery.js:381)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:203)
at jQuery.fn.init._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (bootstrap.js:1503)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:1563)
at Function.each (jquery.js:381)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:203)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:1558)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5429)
```

I am not able to figure out what is the issue Pls help.

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaZkZ.png)

Comment: Can you see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968327/how-to-add-bootstrap-accordion-to-angular-app) if it can help you?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your HTML Bootstrap Jquery . probably a javascript error!!!

Comment: @K Raja Sharma please show it on codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with `"jquery": "^3.5.0"`

Downgrading to `"jquery": "3.4.1"` fixes it (make sure you remove ^).

If you must use 3.5.0, try modifying manually:

```
node_modules/bootsrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js line 1509
```

change

```
if (!data && _config.toggle && /show|hide/.test(config))
```

to

```
if (!data && _config.toggle && /show|hide/.test(_config))
```

Comment: This is the solution to issue. Thanks Victor.

Answer (score 0):

please check with Bootstrap CDN. if that works then something wrong in your node_modules.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">. 
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">. 
</script>
```

copy above CDN to index.html `<head>` tag should work.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working that way. But need to work with node modules can you pls tell how figure that out.

Comment: if above CDN is working then something wrong with your node_modules can u delete node_modules and do npm install again and check?